# twilio send sms not working in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio node for sending sms. but I am getting error:

> sendSms is not defined

Here is my twilio file inside server folder:

```
import twilio from "twilio";
sms = {
    accountSid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authToken: "your_auth_token"
};

const client = new twilio(sms.accountSid, sms.authToken);
console.log('client twilio *********** ',client)
sendSms=(phoneNum,randomNum)=> {
    client
    .sendSms({
        body: "MicroTM one time password:" + randomNum,
        to: phoneNum,
        from: "+16062631146"
    })
    .then((message, err) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(message);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Now when I console twilio, I was unable to find the sendSms function.
Here are the logs:

```
client twilio ***********  Twilio {
I20170813-08:14:44.200(5.5)?   username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
I20170813-08:14:44.201(5.5)?   password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
I20170813-08:14:44.202(5.5)?   accountSid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
I20170813-08:14:44.204(5.5)?   httpClient: {},
I20170813-08:14:44.204(5.5)?   region: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.205(5.5)?   _accounts: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.206(5.5)?   _api: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.207(5.5)?   _chat: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.208(5.5)?   _fax: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.209(5.5)?   _ipMessaging: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.209(5.5)?   _lookups: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.210(5.5)?   _monitor: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.210(5.5)?   _notify: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.211(5.5)?   _preview: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.211(5.5)?   _pricing: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.212(5.5)?   _taskrouter: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.212(5.5)?   _trunking: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.212(5.5)?   _video: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.213(5.5)?   _messaging: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.213(5.5)?   _wireless: undefined,
I20170813-08:14:44.214(5.5)?   _sync: undefined }
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MicroTM",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "busboy": "^0.2.14",
    "fibers": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "twilio": "^3.6.2"
  }
}
```

There might be some issue with the package.json file as I am unable to find any issue with twilio api.

**EDIT:**

Here is my client side where I called the send sms function:

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let fullName = event.target.fullName.value,
            phoneNum = event.target.phoneNum.value,
            email = event.target.emailsignup.value,
            password = event.target.passwordsignup.value,
            confirmPass = event.target.passwordsignup_confirm.value;
            console.log(phoneNum,email,password,confirmPass);
        let randomNum = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
        let data = {
            fullName: fullName,
            phoneNum: phoneNum, 
            email:email, 
            password:password, 
            confirmPass:confirmPass,
            otp:randomNum,
            isVerified: false,
            createdAt: Date.now()
        };
        if(password != confirmPass){
            swal({
              title: 'passwords are not matching!',
            })
        }
        else{
            Meteor.call('registerUser',data,function (err,res) {
                if(!err){
                    //console.log('inside result ******* ',data)
                    sendSms(data.phoneNum,randomNum);
                    Router.go('verify')
                }
                else{
                    console.log('error ******* ', err)
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Please also find the screenshot for the error I am getting:
[image]

Comment: make sure client is available in the function

Comment: how can you call a server function on client side??

Comment: you mean I should place the send sms function somewhere accessible to both client as well server

Comment: i think this is not possible, but you can sure send some event using `ajax` or `socket.io` from client to server and pass parameters and after recieving it on server you can call `sendSms` function and pass the recived parameters to it on server.

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem when using other methods of twilio.

Try using method `client.messages.create()`

```
client.messages.create({
        body: "MicroTM one time password:" + randomNum,
        to: phoneNum,
        from: "+16062631146"
    })
    .then((message, err) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(message);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Also be sure to use newer version of twilio and save version to package:

`npm install twilio --save`

**EDIT:** Also there seems you are calling `sendSms method` from a file that is unable to access due to unavailibility of the method in that particular file. Try checking the scope of the function on places you are accessing `sendSms`. Or try posting more of your code here to understand more.

**EDIT2:** You cant call a method defined on server on client side but you could sure send any event using [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) or [socket.io](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/) and pass parameters to server from client. After recieving on server you can call and pass your params to `sendSms` method.May this helps you.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but still no luck.... getting the same console. tried both client.messages.create and npm install twilio --save

Comment: I am passing these arguments from client side(frontend) and these are working fine.

Comment: can you edit your answer so that I can be able to understand more

Comment: Are you sure method is available to all of your files. See the edit.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. The issue with the Twilio client not having a `sendSms` method is because that was available in the version 2 module, but has been removed for version 3. `client.messages.create` is what you need. Good luck with the rest of the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Your declaring `sendSms` function that way so it will be visible in this current scope only.

Replace it with:

```
Meteor.sendSms=(phoneNum,randomNum)=> {
  ...
}
```

And it will be accessible anywhere.

Comment: window does not exist on the server I guess

Comment: @AnkushRishi, oh, thanks, you're right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It is running using Meteor but still I am not getting sendSms function. May be this is a scope error

Comment: @AnkushRishi You should call it `Meteor.sendSms(...)` instead of just `sendSms(...)`